# Read PPM iamge file (P3) and write the output in a FIle using C

Tags: c, ppm

readData should read an Image struct from a .ppm file, write data should write an Image struct in its PPM format to standard output, and free image should free an Image object.

This is what I tried but I am not getting the proper output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

typedef struct Color 
{
    uint8_t R;
    uint8_t G;
    uint8_t B;
} Color;
typedef struct Image
{
    Color **image;
    uint32_t rows;
    uint32_t cols;
} Image;

//Loads an image from a ppm file, and converts to an Image object
extern Image *readData(char *filename);

//Writes an image to stdout
extern void writeData(Image *image);

//Frees an image and all its associated data
extern void freeImage(Image *image);
```

Comment: What output are you getting? How does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: @RetiredNinja I am getting errors and cannot figure out how to solve it

Comment: @SimranMunot What errors?

Comment: @kiranBiradar   UPdated the question with errors

Comment: Please add the errors to your question so anyone reading it has a full picture of what is happening and what you need help with. We shouldn't have to drag more information out piece by piece. For a start, are you sure you're reading the file properly? A P3 file has the colors as text but you are reading them as binary (P6).

Comment: @SimranMunot They are pretty straight forward . ex: `error: ‘img’ undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean ‘image’` What you don't understand in it?

Comment: @kiranBiradar I have declared the img variable. KIndly have a look at the code.

Comment: @SimranMunot You don't have anything called `img` in your `writeData` function.

Comment: Read each error carefully and look at the code generating it. In the first you are using the wrong name for a variable in the struct, `data` versus `image`. You are also using the wrong name of a variable `img` versus `image` for the next error.

Comment: I did solve the errors. Now I am getting segmentation fault. @RetiredNinja

Comment: @SimranMunot     `image->data = (Color*)malloc(image -> rows * image->cols * sizeof(Color));` but data is of type `Color **`.

Comment: still the same error @kiranBiradar

Comment: Also `3 * image->rows, image->cols` this is wrong calculation of bytes, remember `fread` and `fwrite` takes number of bytes as input.

Comment: SO how will the code become? @kiranBiradar

Answer (score 0):

We can use fscanf, it ignores spaces and newline.
This will help in reading the data and solve the problem.